# Cannot change tempo in midi with "Set_Tempo"

Tags: python, midi, tempo, mido

I am trying to change a tempo in a midi file with the mido library using the MetaMessage('set_tempo', tempo=tempo, time=tiem) attribute to the tempotrack. When setting the initial tempo to 552528 with time = 0, the bpm is correctly set to 108.59178. However, When I set the tempo to 552540, the bpm stays at 108.59178 when it should be 108.5894. There seems to be similar discrepancies when setting to similar tempos, is there a midi setting that causes this? The program I am loading the midi into for testing is Pro Tools. The midi ticks_per_beat is 9600, and is available here: https://ufile.io/jhz771gh

I have no idea where to go from here or how to further test so ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That link does not work, and you have not shown your code. Create a MIDI file containing only the set_tempo message, and show a hex dump of that.

Comment: You are trying to see the difference in the fifth digit. Very likely, your software just rounds it out.